# tablesorter math widget return N/A with tablesorter-childRow

Tags: math, widget, tablesorter

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>1st</th>
        <th>2nd</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
        <td colspan="2">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>3rd</th>
                        <th>4th</th>
                        <th>5th</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-math="col-sum"></th>
                        <th data-math="col-sum"></th>
                        <th data-math="col-sum"></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

this is the table structure and I am using tablesorter with math midget every thing is working fine in the main table but inside the childrow table it's returns N/A or not existed col and the sum for existed ones is the sum of the main table

"it's work for main table only"

please help how to make this work for both table the outer and the inner

I tried to include the inner table into div but the same problem is still
I also tried to change the class for the second table and the problem is still the same

http://jsfiddle.net/vCTHw/1258/

Comment: This looks like a bug in the math widget... it's finding the nested table math cell, but it can't find an associated column, so it is putting the "N/A" value there. I'll have this problem fixed in the master branch shortly.

Comment: Ok, all fixed in v2.24.4... here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yoqp84wm/

Comment: thanks , Mottie it works like charm